# Add Days methods

Tags: c#, date, datetime, methods

I have to create a class that includes 3 methods.
1st - It shows current date
2nd - current date + 7days
3rd - current date - 7days.

I had completely dealing with dates in C # so i created sth that :

```
    public class Date
    {
        private DateTime date = DateTime.Now; 

        public  DateTime Now()
        {
            return date; 
        }
        public  DateTime AktuPlusOne ()
        {
            DateTime date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
            return date;
        }

        public DateTime AktuMinusOne()
        {
            DateTime date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
            return date; 
        }
    }
```

Is it ok or not ? It works fine, but I care about good habits .

Comment: `Is it ok or not ?` What is the crireria for being OK?

Comment: Why would you need to create a separate class that shows the date? DateTime Does that already.

Comment: The code contains good practices :)

Comment: It's such a requirement

Answer (score 1):

No need to create additional method as framework already provides this functionality out of box `DateTime.Now.AddDays(numberOfDays)`. However, if you really want to create a generic method for your requirement, just create one instead of three methods.

```
public  DateTime AddDaysToToday(int days)
{
    return DateTime.Now.AddDays(days);
}

DateTime today = AddDaysToToday(0);
DateTime todayPlusSeven = AddDaysToToday(7);
DateTime todayMinusSeven = AddDaysToToday(-7);
```